# Having troubles finding Regular Solids with blender 2.78

Tags: add-on

I am new to Blender and I have been watching a video tutorial on how to create a soccer ball. So this guy went to Addons then Add Mesh and he enabled Regular Solids. I am using blender v2.78 and I don't have this option. I am trying to create a Truncated Icosahedron shape.

Comment: I did see that answer but he didn't show how to make a Truncated Icosahedron shape. Anyways, I got my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Go to File -> User Preferences -> Add-ons and under Categories click on Add Mesh and enable Extra Objects.

[image]

2- Click on Add -> Mesh -> Math Function -> Regular Solid.

[image]

3- Press "T" to bring up the tools (if it is not opened already) and under (Regular) solids scroll down till you see Presets and select "Truncated Icosahedron".

[image]

Good luck!